# Saving values in different pages in a gridview,asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid which contains more than 30 values.Grid view page size is 10 .Grid view also contains check box when i select two datas in  first page and go to next page and select another two data and enter ok button only save last select value.I want to save all datas that i selected in different pages

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this piece of code:
*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
BindGridData();
}
}
//This method is used to bind the gridview
protected void BindGridData()
{
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=XXX;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
gvdetails.DataSource = ds;
gvdetails.DataBind();
}
protected void gvdetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
SaveCheckedValues();
gvdetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
BindGridData();
PopulateCheckedValues();
}
//This method is used to populate the saved checkbox values
private void PopulateCheckedValues()
{
ArrayList userdetails = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
if (userdetails != null && userdetails.Count > 0)
{
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvdetails.Rows)
{
int index = (int)gvdetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value;
if (userdetails.Contains(index))
{
CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect");
myCheckBox.Checked = true;
}
}
}
}
//This method is used to save the checkedstate of values
private void SaveCheckedValues()
{
ArrayList userdetails = new ArrayList();
int index = -1;
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvdetails.Rows)
{
index = (int)gvdetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value;
bool result = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
// Check in the Session
if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
userdetails = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
if (result)
{
if (!userdetails.Contains(index))
userdetails.Add(index);
}
else
userdetails.Remove(index);
}
if (userdetails != null && userdetails.Count > 0)
Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = userdetails;
}
```

*